# How to automatically copy and paste ONLY 'single quoted' text from auto prompt inside a for loop?

Tags: linux, shell

I am using a command to retrieve multiple expired directories using for loop. And system has a safety check and wants to make sure I am human.

```
$ for x in $(exp-dir); do 
clean_command $x
done
```

system will auto-prompt interactive shell and I am supposed to copy and paste quoted text (for each $x in the for loop) to complete:

```
$ to verify that you are human, please type 'xyzylans':
you are human
Info: restore successful.
```

Is there any way I can parse, copy and pass the single quoted text, so to say, automate the loop fully!

Comment: You may have to use [tag:expect] for this.

Comment: Does the script write to stdout and read from stdin or from /dev/tty? Is the output line always the same except for the string `xyzylans`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging: it's not a script, I am running this for loop on command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat testscript.sh
#! /bin/bash

string='xyzylans'
echo "to verify that you are human, please type '${string}':"
read cmpstring
test "$string" = "$cmpstring"
echo $?
```

If `stdin` and `stdout` are used, then you can do this:

```
coproc ./testscript.sh
awk -F\' "/^to verify that you are human, please type '.*':\$/ "\
"{ print \$2; exit };" <&${COPROC[0]} >&${COPROC[1]}
cat <&${COPROC[0]}
```

Comment: string in the quotes is auto-generated and for each value of $x in the for loop.